# converting money format to string in sql

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I have an application in c# where I retrieve data from database where the amount column in sql is decimal (19,4)
Court Fee is int and solictors cost is float and total amount is int.

```
amount = 100.0000
court fee = 15
solictors fee = 0
total amount = 115.0000
```

but the output I am looking for should be in this format.

```
`0010000(7) 01500(5) 00000(5) 00011500(8).`
```

can this be possible. I am new to c# just struggling to convert this format to string..

Comment: Your question is not clear.

Comment: i want to convert  100.0000 to  010000 in c#

Comment: you want only 2 units after the decimal place?

Comment: You can rewrite your question to clarify what to got and what do you want. As far as I understand you want to put leading zeros on a numeric valued column. If that's what do you want you don't need to update the values, just format the output. Is that right?

Comment: yes jean  i want leading zeros for a numeric valued column(decimal(19,4)

Comment: 010000 is like ten thousand right? So either you are missing a "." or I am missing something else..

Comment: Why do you convert 100.00 to 7 symbols and 150.00 to 8 symbols?

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to update your values or "convert". Do you want to format the output like:

```
SELECT RIGHT('0000000'+ CONVERT(VARCHAR, MyColumn),7) AS MyOutput FROM MyTable
```

Comment: result is 00.0000 but i want 0010000

Comment: Is your numeric data persisted as varchar instead of decimal, integer or float?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it myself..
I wrote this ..its solved..

`"RIGHT('00'+CAST(CAST(bat.PCN_Charge* 100.00 AS INT) AS VARCHAR(5)),8)" +`